# Mocha / Sinon / Node - My done call is never invoked. Any idea what the issue could be?

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, sinon

I've been trying to figure this out for the better part of three or four hours, and I'm completely at a loss. I never access the inside of the `end` function. The test just times out with

`Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`

Any idea what the issue could be?

```
const ClientsControllerStub = {
  create: sinon.spy(),
  index: sinon.spy()
};

describe('GET', function () {
  it('should invoke the clients controller\'s index action', function (done) {
    chai.request(app)
      .get('/clients')
      .end(function(error, response) {
        console.log(error, response);
        expect(ClientsControllerStub.index).to.have.been.called;
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Here's the controller:

'use strict';

```
const express = require('express');
const Client = require('../models/user');

exports.create = (req, res) => {
  console.log('Create');
  res.send('This has yet to be implemented.');
};
exports.index = (req, res) => {
  console.log('Index');
  res.send({});
};
exports.show = (req, res) => {
  console.log('Show');
  res.send('This has yet to be implemented.');
};
exports.destroy = (req, res) => {
  console.log('Destroy');
  res.send('This has yet to be implemented.');
};
exports.update = (req, res) => {
  console.log('Update');
  res.send('This has yet to be implemented.');
};
```

Comment: what happens when your curl or use postman to send that same request, does it hang?

Comment: No, it hits the index action of my controller. I'll update my post to contain the controller's code.

Comment: the line `.send('lkajsdlkjasf')` looks suspicious. have you tried removing it?

Comment: It is definitely suspicious. I've removed it, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Have you got the app configured with a url ? Because it looks like the request is never made. Can you try     chai.request('localhost:xxxx' or the server address)?.

Comment: I figured it out. I'll answer my own question in a bit.